# angular pipes that contain custom components html

Tags: angular, pipe

Imagine a pipe like this:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'addIcon' })
export class AddIconPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor() {}
  transform(value) {
    return (
      `
      <div class="icon">
        <app-icon name="welcome"></app-icon>
      </div>
    ` + value
    );
  }
```

When you will use this pipe like `{{ 'Garry' | appIcon }}`
you will get the next result:

```
<div class="icon">
</div>
Garry
```

but expected result is:

```
<div class="icon">
  <app-icon>
    contents of the app-icon component..., for example
    <img src="welcome.jpg" />
  </app-icon>
</div>
Garry
```

It seems that custom components in the pipe do not renders at all.

How can I render a custom component html using a pipe?

Comment: Have you thought about using content projection in a component for this?

Comment: provide an example please, so I could understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I honestly can't find any scenario where you prefer to render a DOM element from pipe and not from `Directive`.

You can inject the `ElementRef` in the `directive` ctor.

Pipes should only transform values, and can optimize the transformation with being pure and don't recalculate for every change in the objects.

Comment: how can you conditionally add custom directive to a html element?

Comment: <div [attr.DIRECTIVE_SELECTOR]="condition ? '' : null"></div>

Comment: and how you can pass a paramter to it's constructor? without adding extra Input fields?